# LocalNotification: Notification with vibration and floating message whit Codename One

Tags: android, push-notification, codenameone

I need my application to show a notification when the application is in the foreground. **I have two problems**.

**1)** I wish that upon receiving the notification a vibration is emitted. I don't know how to do it using "LocalNotification". Of course I have tried:

```
Display.getInstance().vibrate(1000);
```

without success.

**2)** The other problem is that only an icon appears in the status bar, but to read the notification it is necessary to display the status bar. The rest of my applications do show the floating message.

```
LocalNotification ln = new LocalNotification();
        ln.setId("LnMessage");
        ln.setAlertTitle("Welcome");
        ln.setAlertBody("Hello world!");
        Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(ln, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10, LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE);
```

**I need this:**

> [image]

**But i have only this:**

> [image]

**EDIT:** I have resolved the vibration issue in the following way.
Right click on the project
codename one>>CodenameOne settings>>advanced settings>>Build hints

> key= android.permission.VIBRATE value = true

Then `Display.getInstance.vibrate(1000);`
It works well for me.

Comment: I invested an hour or so to find out in android docs a way to show out a notification like this, but I haven't found any information. It is android default notification, so source code should be open within platform. I will follow this question in case anyone can share an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When the application is in the foreground you need to show the message on your own. You can show a `Toast` message when a notification callback is received so it will also appear visually in the UI.

There's [this issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3702) with vibrate. But it seems we will need to address it ourselves at some point.

Comment: Ok, I had thought about creating my own notification. As for the vibration, I managed to solve it. I have edited the question and posted the solution in case it can help someone. Thank you very much Shai

Comment: You can use the `Toast` class for this custom notification. It can be heavily customized with CSS.